# Main.m and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appdelegate

When I delete my app on iPhone and Run the project from `Xcode`, the app gets installed on the device and the first screen of the app is loaded. But the breakpoints in `main.m` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` are not triggered, even the `viewDidLoad` of the first screen is not called. After some time the push notification permission delegates in `AppDelegate` class get's called. This problem occurs only when I delete and reinstall the app.